# How can I add rounded corners to a bitmap in Fireworks

Tags: adobe-fireworks

I have a bitmap which I want to crop (using a vector) with rounded corners I can't because I need 2 or more paths? How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways, one with selections and another one with masks.

For selections, you can [check this tutorial](http://www.joycejevans.com/tutorials/Fireworks/FWMX/roundecorners/rc_crn.htm). It basically creates a shape to use as the extraction. You have to select the Rounded Rectangle tool and in the Property inspector set the roundness to the value you want. Then draw a rectangle without fill over your image, paste image inside it and delete the stroke.

If you prefer masks (way better, because it can be easy to adapt), [check this one](http://featofdesign.com/stephen/2011/07/17/fireworks-cs5-5-round-corners-on-images-and-adding-vector-masks/#.UBiBnWFa7CU). In this case, you draw a shape with round corners and paste it as a mask (Edit > Paste as Mask) on top of the photo. The advantage is nor only the editing possibilities, but the re-using of this mask in other photos.